# remove objects without foreign keys in jpa controller

Tags: mysql, database, jpa

here is my code,

**SiteMember class**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "member",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MemberThread> memberThread = new ArrayList<MemberThread>
```

and

**MemberThread class**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    private SiteMember member;
```

**MemberThreadJpaController class**

```
public void destroy(Long id) throws IllegalOrphanException, NonexistentEntityException, NotSupportedException, RollbackException, HeuristicMixedException, HeuristicRollbackException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, SystemException {
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = getEntityManager();
            ut.begin();
            MemberThread memberThread;
            try {
                memberThread = em.getReference(MemberThread.class, id);
                memberThread.getId();
            } catch (EntityNotFoundException enfe) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The memberThread with id " + id + " no longer exists.", enfe);
            }
            List<String> illegalOrphanMessages = null;
            List<Reply> replysOrphanCheck = memberThread.getReplys();
            for (Reply replysOrphanCheckReply : replysOrphanCheck) {
                if (illegalOrphanMessages == null) {
                    illegalOrphanMessages = new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                illegalOrphanMessages.add("This MemberThread (" + memberThread + ") cannot be destroyed since the Reply " + replysOrphanCheckReply + " in its replys field has a non-nullable memberThread field.");
            }
            if (illegalOrphanMessages != null) {
                throw new IllegalOrphanException(illegalOrphanMessages);
            }
            SiteMember member = memberThread.getMember();
            if (member != null) {
                member.getMemberThread().remove(memberThread);
                member = em.merge(member);
            }
            em.remove(memberThread);
            ut.commit();
        } finally {
            if (em != null) {
                em.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

this will remove both SiteMember and MemberThread objects because MemberThread has a foreign key of SiteMember.how can i remove only MemberThread?

thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Analysis

In your MemeberThread class you have a SiteMember with a CascadeType.ALL. CascadeType tells what kind of cascading operations to invoke when doing changes in persistent context.

From [CascadeType API](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/CascadeType):

> Defines the set of cascadable operations that are propagated to the
>   associated entity. The value cascade=ALL is equivalent to
>   cascade={PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH}.

Invoking em.remove(memberThread) will cascade all operations on SiteMember by removing it.

## Solution

**Change your cascade type for SiteMember in MemberThread class**:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={
    CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, 
    CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH
})
@JoinColumn(nullable=false)
private SiteMember member;
```

Now REMOVE operation will not be cascaded.

Comment: could you tell me what does "CascadeType.DETACH" do? my API doesn't have it.why?

Comment: It detaches. Google for JPA entity lifecycle in persistence context to understand all types. Your API do not have DETACH? What is fully qualified name for CascadeType?